# Change handlers aren't updating values in added object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table that renders data based on an api call and a select dropdown. When a checkbox is selected the `name` key and it's value get added to an object of arrays called `selectedFields`

```
  checkbox = ({ name, isChecked }) => {
//handle check box of each fieldName
if (isChecked === true) {
  //checked conditional
  this.setState(
    { selectedFields: [...this.state.selectedFields, { name }] });
} else {
  this.setState({
      selectedFields: this.state.selectedFields.filter(f => f.name !== name)
    });
}
```

};

When a checkbox is selected the data structure ends up looking like this:

```
  "selectedFields": [
    {
      "name": "author"
    }
   ]
```

There's also 3 inputs values (`lengthType`, `size`, etc.) that need to be entered by the user and update inside the same object that was selected.

Currently I cannot get the value to update to the corresponding `name` object.

My desired structure is

```
  "selectedFields": [
    {
      "name": "author",
      "lengthType": "fixed",
      "size": "1"
    }
  ]
```

So in the index file the `handleChange` and the `onLengthTypeChange` handlers need to be changed to add those updated values back to the `[name_obj]` but I'm not sure how.

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7jnvlnj0y) with the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `Dropdown` handler to this:

```
onLengthTypeChange = ({ currentTarget: { textContent } }, name) => {
  const { selectedFields } = this.state;
  if (selectedFields.some(elem => elem.name === name)) {
    this.setState({
      selectedFields: [
        ...selectedFields.map(elem =>
          elem.name !== name
            ? elem
            : {
                name,
                lengthType: textContent
              }
        )
      ]
    });
  }
};
```

You would also need to check if there already are any values in the select input on your checkbox handler, in order to add them to the state along with the name. But I think a better solution would be to just disable the row inputs if the checkbox is not checked.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I was definitely looking for a one function solution and this one covers that. I couldn't quite tweak my original handlers to achieve this. And yes I plan to disable the row inputs if the box is not checked. I appreciate your time.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you.

Comment: Any idea how I can update `handleChange` so the two number inputs aren't overwriting `lengthType`? I've updated my sandbox here ---> https://codesandbox.io/s/o7jnvlnj0y

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you seem to have. What exactly is getting overwritten?